# Data Validation, Complex, based on another sheet

Tags: google-sheets

Sample sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HNIEQ---mTgRAYuGTffuSJ7Yggi4rQeRkNba5R-Di90/edit#gid=1837884456).

Have 2 sheets; DataTemplate stores the validation keys and DataValidation is the sheet that should include data validation based on said keys.

Eg: DataValidation!B11:E17 is validated against DataTemplate!B11:E17 (please see sample)

Sample validation requirements:

1. IF coressponding DataTemplate value == -500 then Cell must be blank
2. IF coressponding DataTemplate value == -200 then Cell must be blank or positive number
3. IF coressponding DataTemplate value > 0 then Cell must be a number between 0..1 OR a string in [ "A", "B", "C" ]

I've attemped this with formulae like below but other than very simple validation available on the net, I've not been able to make anything work.

```
=SWITCH(INDIRECT("DataTemplate!D11:E17"),-500,ISBLANK(D11),-200,OR(ISNUMBER(D11),ISBLANK(D11),OR(ISNUMBER(D11),IFERROR(MATCH(D11,SPLIT("A,B,C",","),FALSE),FALSE)>0)
```

EDIT; solved thanks to Jeremy Kahan (below).

My issue was, I was trying to apply Conditional Formatting rules to Conditional Validation, but apparently they are quite different in terms of their application (I do believe). Eg: you can directly access cells in other sheets, you write a normal formula for the top left cell of the range you are applying to. My actual validation formula is given below.

```
=SWITCH(WorkArrivals!D11,
  -500,ISBLANK(D11),
  -400,ISBLANK(D11),
  -200,AND(NOT(ISBLANK(D11)),OR(AND(ISNUMBER(D11),D11>0,D11<1),NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("|"&D11&"|","|absent|sick|annual|family|domtravel|inttravel|"))))),
  -100,OR(ISBLANK(D11),AND(ISNUMBER(D11),D11>0,D11<1),NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("|"&D11&"|","|domtravel|inttravel|")))),
  AND(NOT(ISBLANK(D11)),OR(AND(ISNUMBER(D11),D11>0,D11<1),NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("|"&D11&"|","|absent|sick|annual|family|domtravel|inttravel|")))))
)
```

Tips:

1. No way to validate NOT(ISBLANK()) as (it appears) validation is triggered when data is entered ONLY.
2. Similar to Conditional Formatting, it appears that the whole (applied) range is validated and NOT just the cell that was updated. There is a (background active progress bar) lag (~2s for range(1000 rows, 15 cols) - so use with caution on large ranges. @Google could make this smarter ?

Comment: IsNumber is true even for 0 or negative numbers.  Replace IsNumber(D11) with And(IsNumber(D11),D11>0). Also, I think that last OR is hard to read. The case should just be like the AND I just made, the result should be like (assuming floating point not an issue) OR(AND(D11>0,D11<1),OR(D11="A",D11="B",D11="C")). In general, it probably makes sense to test each rule by itself, then add them into your switch.

Comment: But I am not sure switch can handle your rule 3 (though maybe yes, since it seems to be your default case), which will mean part of what I just suggested is off, sorry. Even though ugly, nesting some =IF might be better here.

Comment: Also, IsNumber need numbers to be formatted as numbers. Your 122 is not.

Comment: Once you format the numbers as numbers, the below should work: =SWITCH(DataTemplate!B11,-500,ISBLANK(B11),-200,OR(IsBlank(B11),AND(IsNumber(B11),B11>0)),OR(NOT(AND(IsNumber(DataTemplate!B11),DataTemplate!B11>0)),AND(B11>0,B11<1),B11="A",B11="B",B11="C"))

Comment: I had my test data in B11. You may want D11

Comment: ISBlank(B11:B17)  has a size different from D11:E17, so an array formula may not know how to handle it. Do you need this ti use an array formula as opposed to something you drag and copy?

Comment: I think the below, dragged around, will work and is more readable than the array formula or the switch. =if(DataTemplate!B11=-500,IsBlank(D11),if(DataTemplate!B11=-200,OR(ISBlank(B11),B11>0),if(DataTemplate!B11>0,OR(AND(B11>0,B11<1),B11="A",B11="B",B11="C"),true)))

Comment: @JeremyKahan Thank you for your help. I've managed to solve the issue based on your feedback. I have edited the OP with my solution and observations. Is there any way to validate NOT(ISBLANK()) to ensure a cell should not be blank?

Comment: I am glad that helped. I do not know how to fix the NOT(IsBlank) not triggering issue, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Solved thanks to Jeremy Kahan (below). For the benefit of other users;

My issue was, I was trying to apply Conditional Formatting rules to Conditional Validation, but apparently they are quite different in terms of their application (I do believe). Eg: you can directly access cells in other sheets, you write a normal formula for the top left cell of the range you are applying to. My actual validation formula is given below.

```
=SWITCH(WorkArrivals!D11,
  -500,ISBLANK(D11),
  -400,ISBLANK(D11),
  -200,AND(NOT(ISBLANK(D11)),OR(AND(ISNUMBER(D11),D11>0,D11<1),NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("|"&D11&"|","|absent|sick|annual|family|domtravel|inttravel|"))))),
  -100,OR(ISBLANK(D11),AND(ISNUMBER(D11),D11>0,D11<1),NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("|"&D11&"|","|domtravel|inttravel|")))),
  AND(NOT(ISBLANK(D11)),OR(AND(ISNUMBER(D11),D11>0,D11<1),NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("|"&D11&"|","|absent|sick|annual|family|domtravel|inttravel|")))))
)
```

Tips:

1. No way to validate NOT(ISBLANK()) as (it appears) validation is triggered when data is entered ONLY.
2. Similar to Conditional Formatting, it appears that the whole (applied) range is validated and NOT just the cell that was updated. There is a (background active progress bar) lag (~2s for range(1000 rows, 15 cols) - so use with caution on large ranges. @Google could make this smarter ?